# Pandas groupby datetime and count value by only time and ignoring date

Tags: pandas, dataframe, datetime

To make it very simple, I now have a dataframe P1 with a datetime index, columns: trade price and the daily trade average. Id like to count the number of trades done when they are above the daily average for each day.

```
P1[P1['Trade Price'] > P1['Pavg']].resample('5min').count()
```

This would give me the 5min interval for the counts i like but this would break into different days. Is there a way where i can count the value i want by ignoring the date? so the count only take into account of the Time of the dates?

Answer (score 0):

Try with `groupby`

```
s=P1[P1['Trade Price'] > P1['Pavg']].copy()
s.groupby(s.index.date).resample('5min').count()
```

Comment: Hi mate, thanks for the suggestion but got an error with "Grouper and axis must be same length"

Comment: @kit12_31 try again

Comment: Hi mate, i found another way last night:         count = P1['Trade Price'][P1['Trade Price'] > P1['Pavg']].resample('5min').count() then put it in a dataframe, countd = pd.DataFrame(data=count) follow by countd.pivot_table(countd,index=countd.index.time, aggfunc=np.sum)